# How to read a GAMS gms file into ROI (R Optimisation Interface)?

Tags: r, gams-math, neos-server, r-optimization

I have a NLP model written in GAMS and I would like to use ROI (R Optimisation Interface) to send it to the NEOS Server.

It looks like ROI_read() is the command for reading in external models, but I don't know how to find out or install the correct reader type/plugin.

```
Sys.setenv(ROI_LOAD_PLUGINS = FALSE)
library(ROI)             # ROI_solve
library(ROI.plugin.neos) # NEOS

x <- ROI_read("rawdata/mymodel.gms", type = "GAMS", solver = "neos")

Error in ROI_read("rawdata/mymodel.gms", type = "GAMS", solver = "neos") : 
  no reader found for type 'GAMS'
```

Answer (score 1):

`ROI` doesn't have a method for reading GAMS models. What it does when sending a model to the NEOS server it is writing the model as GAMS format and sending this file.

Suppose you have the following model saved as `model.gms`

```
Option IntVarUp = 0;

Set i / R1*R3 / ;
Set ileq(i) / R1, R2, R3 / ;
Set j / C1*C3 / ;

Parameter objL(j)
/C1 2
C2 4
C3 3/ ;

Parameter rhs(i)
/R1 60
R2 40
R3 80/ ;

Parameter A
/R1.C1 3
R2.C1 2
R3.C1 1
R1.C2 4
R2.C2 1
R3.C2 3
R1.C3 2
R2.C3 2
R3.C3 2/;

Variables obj;
Positive Variables x(j);


Equations
    ObjSum
    LinLeq(ileq);

ObjSum .. obj =e= sum(j, x(j) * objL(j)) ;
LinLeq(ileq) .. sum(j, A(ileq, j) * x(j)) =l= rhs(ileq) ;

Model LinearProblem /all/ ;

Solve LinearProblem using LP maximizing obj ;

option decimals = 8;

display '---BEGIN.SOLUTION---', x.l, '---END.SOLUTION---';


file results /results.txt/;
results.nw = 0;
results.nd = 15;
results.nr = 2;
results.nz = 0;
put results;
put 'solution:'/;
loop(j, put, x.l(j)/);
put 'objval:'/;
put LinearProblem.objval/;
put 'solver_status:'/;
put LinearProblem.solvestat/;
put 'model_status:'/;
put LinearProblem.modelstat/;
```

Then you could modify the `solve_op` function from `ROI.plugin.neos` in the following way to achieve what you want.

```
Sys.setenv(ROI_LOAD_PLUGINS = FALSE)
library(ROI)
#> ROI: R Optimization Infrastructure
#> Registered solver plugins: nlminb.
#> Default solver: auto.
library(ROI.plugin.neos)
model <- paste0(readLines('model.gms'), collapse = '\n')

control <- ROI.plugin.neos:::set_default_control_values(ROI.plugin.neos:::neos_control())
control$email <- YOUR_EMAIL

solver_name <- "scip"

xml <- ROI.plugin.neos:::neos_xml_call(model, solver_name, control)
solver_call <- list(ROI.plugin.neos:::neos_submit_job, x = NULL, xmlstring = xml, user = control$user, 
                        password = control$password)
mode(solver_call) <- "call"
job <- eval(solver_call)
sol <- job$solution(wait=TRUE)
str(sol)
#> List of 4
#>  $ solution: num [1:3] 0 6.67 16.67
#>  $ objval  : num NA
#>  $ status  :List of 2
#>   ..$ code: int 0
#>   ..$ msg :List of 5
#>   .. ..$ solver  : chr "neos"
#>   .. ..$ code    : int 1
#>   .. ..$ symbol  : chr "NORMAL_COMPLETION"
#>   .. ..$ message : chr "An optimal solution was obtained."
#>   .. ..$ roi_code: int 0
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "registry_entry"
#>  $ message :List of 5
#>   ..$ solution     : num [1:3] 0 6.67 16.67
#>   ..$ objval       : num 76.7
#>   ..$ solver_status: num 1
#>   ..$ model_status : num 1
#>   ..$ message      : chr "Executed on prod-exec-1.neos-server.org\nGAMS 39.1.0  5f04cd76 May 3, 2022           LEX-LEG x86 64bit/Linux - "| __truncated__
#>  - attr(*, "meta")=List of 1
#>   ..$ solver: chr "neos"
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "neos_solution" "OP_solution"
```

The drawback of this approach is that the default printing method of `ROI` for the solution won't work any longer and that you have to select the solver `manually`.

A better approach would be to save the model in GAMS to fixed MPS format or any other format which `ROI` can actually read.

Answer (score 1):

The new [GAMS Studio](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/T_STUDIO.html) has an [integrated NEOS interface](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/T_STUDIO.html#STUDIO_NEOS) that allows you to solve your model on NEOS from within GAMS Studio. Also see this [blog post](https://www.gams.com/blog/2020/11/running-large-models-on-neos-for-free/).

[Submitting data to NEOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcA5D.png)